# IE11: empty http request header not being passed

Tags: javascript, ajax, http, internet-explorer, http-headers

I am facing an issue on IE where in my `http` request the request header is being ignored in cased the value of header is empty string `''`. This breaks my application. It works well on chrome. But fails on IE as IE seems to exclude headers with blank value from request. Any solution to fix this?

Services use this as a check. Hence I cant change the empty header approach.

TIA.

Comment: What about adding a value to the header ?

Comment: Services use this as a check. Hence I cant change the empty header approach.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I could not find any solution that makes IE pass empty headers with http request. Hence I had to change the convention and instead pass `null` as a string to simulate this.

```
'null'
```